# How this if condition is unreachable?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, unreachable-code

`IsSaveNew` is type of `bool?` 
`CoverLetterId` is type of `int?`

```
if (coverLetter.IsSaveNew ?? true || coverLetter.CoverLetterId == null)
```

`coverLetter.CoverLetterId == null`. This statement is marked as unreachable in visual studio(2012).

But if `IsSaveNew` was false, then it would reach at the second condition. Why Visual Studio says so?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like an operator precedence issue. Your statement is evaluated as:

```
if (coverLetter.IsSaveNew ?? (true || coverLetter.CoverLetterId == null))
```

So the right-hand operand to the `||` operator will never be evaluated since its left-hand operand is the literal `true`.

You can add parentheses to solve this problem:

```
if ((coverLetter.IsSaveNew ?? true) || coverLetter.CoverLetterId == null)
```

Comment: But still visual studio says its unreachable

Comment: @SubinJacob, do you have an actual warning in the output pane during the build, or is it only Intellisense marking the expression as unreachable?

Comment: Sorry, That was the problem with the intellisense. When I compiled, it got corrected. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

[`||`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6373h346.aspx) has highger precedence than [`??`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) operator.

Check out [`7.2.1 Operator precedence and associativity`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691323%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Your `true || coverLetter.CoverLetterId == null` works first. If you want `coverLetter.IsSaveNew ?? true` should work first, just use parentheses around it.

Like;

```
if ((coverLetter.IsSaveNew ?? true) || coverLetter.CoverLetterId == null)
```

> But still visual studio says its unreachable

That means (probably) your `coverLetter.IsSaveNew ?? true` returns `true`, that's why your second operand doesn't evaluate.

From [`|| Operator (C# Reference)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6373h346.aspx)

> **If the first operand evaluates to true, the second operand isn't
>   evaluated**. If the first operand evaluates to false, the second
>   operator determines whether the OR expression as a whole evaluates to
>   true or false.

Comment: Even after adding (), the warning remains. However, the code executes perfectly when false is passed

Comment: @SubinJacob I think you are using some plugin in Visual Studio. That means your `coverLetter.IsSaveNew ?? true` returns `true`. That could means 2 things: Either your `coverLetter.IsSaveNewis` is `null` **OR** your `coverLetter.IsSaveNewis` is `true`.

Answer (score 1):

You can put **coverLetter.IsSaveNew ?? true** in paranthesis to solve this.
like-

```
if ((coverLetter.IsSaveNew ?? true) || coverLetter.CoverLetterId == null)
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd better use GetValueOrDefault as the ?? part will always evaluate to true